# Exception in Thread - Multi-Threaded Lotto Program

Tags: java, multithreading

I am getting an Exception that I am unable to resolve.

```
package advanced.net;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

public class LottoClient {

    private InetAddress serverAddress;

    private int serverPort = LottoProtocol.SERVER_PORT;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Starting Client");
        LottoClient lottoClient1 = null;
        lottoClient1 = new LottoClient(); // This was not a TODO
        lottoClient1.startClient(args);
    }

    public LottoClient() {
    }

    private String getTicketFromServer() {
        String lotteryTicket = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null; // to get response from server
        PrintWriter writer = null; // to send request to server
        System.out.println("Getting Ticket");
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddress, serverPort);

            InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
            OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            writer = new PrintWriter(out, true); // true for autoflush

            lotteryTicket = reader.readLine(); // read the response
        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error getting ticket");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
                if (writer != null) {
                    writer.close();
                }
            } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        // TODO 08. Return the lottery ticket String.
        return lotteryTicket;
    }

    /**
     * configData[0] is the name or IP address of the server
     */
    private void processConfigData(String configData[]) {
        try {
            // set address of server
            if (configData != null && configData.length >= 1) {
                serverAddress = InetAddress.getByName(configData[0]);
            } else {
                // default case is set in our protocol
                String host = LottoProtocol.SERVER_HOST;
                serverAddress = InetAddress.getByName(host);
            }
        } catch (java.net.UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void startClient(String args[]) {
        processConfigData(args);
        String lottoTicket = getTicketFromServer();
        System.out.println(lottoTicket);
    }
}

package advanced.net;

import java.util.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class LottoServer {

    // TODO 01. Make the handler a subclass of Thread.
    private class ClientRequestHandler extends Thread {

        private Socket socket = null;

        public ClientRequestHandler() {
            // Default Constructor
        }

        public ClientRequestHandler(Socket clientSocket) {
            socket = clientSocket;
        }

        /**
         * Generate a lotto ticket. Returns a formatted string containing 6
         * numbers from 1 to 49.
         */
        private String getTicket() {
            int theNumbers[] = new int[LottoProtocol.NUM_OF_NUMBERS];

            for (int i = 0; i < LottoProtocol.NUM_OF_NUMBERS; i++) {
                int newNumber;
                boolean isDuplicate = false;
                do {
                    isDuplicate = false; // reset isDuplicate, in case it has
                    // been set to true

                    // we want the numbers to be in the range of 1 to maxValue
                    // 0 to 48, and then add 1 to make it 1 to 49
                    newNumber = (int) (numberGenerator.nextDouble()
                            * (LottoProtocol.MAX_VALUE - 1) + 1);

                    // Compare to the numbers entered previously, to make sure
                    // it is
                    // not a duplicate.
                    // If it is, then ignore it, and get a new random number.
                    for (int j = 0; j < i && !isDuplicate; j++) {
                        if (newNumber == theNumbers[j]) {
                            isDuplicate = true;
                        }
                    }
                } while (isDuplicate);

                theNumbers[i] = newNumber;
            }
            Arrays.sort(theNumbers);
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            sb.append("Your numbers are: ");
            for (int k = 0; k < LottoProtocol.NUM_OF_NUMBERS; k++) {
                sb.append(String.valueOf(theNumbers[k]) + " ");
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }

        private void handleClientRequests() {
            BufferedReader reader = null; // to read client requests
            PrintWriter writer = null; // to send back response
            String request;

            try {
                InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
                OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                writer = new PrintWriter(out, true); // true for autoflush

                writer.println("LottoServer 1.2");
                request = reader.readLine(); // read client request
                if (request
                        .equalsIgnoreCase(LottoProtocol.TICKET_REQUEST_COMMAND)) {
                    writer.println(getTicket()); // process the request
                }
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                System.err.println("Error processing the request");
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (reader != null) {
                        // TODO 05. Close the reader.
                        reader.close();
                    }
                    if (writer != null) {
                        // TODO 06. Close the writer.
                        writer.close();
                    }
                    if (socket != null) {
                        // TODO 07. Close the client socket.
                        socket.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        public void run() {
            handleClientRequests();
        }

        public Socket getSocket() {
            return socket;
        }

        public void setSocket(Socket socket) {
            this.socket = socket;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LottoServer lottoServer1 = new LottoServer();
        lottoServer1.startServer();
    }

    private Random numberGenerator = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

    private ServerSocket serverSocket = null;

    public LottoServer() {
    }

    private void acceptConnections() {
        Socket clientSocket;
        while (true) {
            try {
                // TODO 02. Get the socket from the client.
                System.out.println("Socket Empty");
                clientSocket = null;
                clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("Socket Captured");
                // TODO 03. Create a new instance of the handler.
                ClientRequestHandler handler = null;
                handler = new ClientRequestHandler();
                System.out.println("Handler Created");
                handler.setSocket(clientSocket);
                Thread thread = new Thread(handler);
                System.out.println("Thread Created");
                // TODO 04. Start the new thread.
                thread.start();
                System.out.println("Thread Started Created");
            } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Error setting up connection");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void createServerSocket() {
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(LottoProtocol.SERVER_PORT);
            System.out.println("Socket Created");
        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            String error = "Error setting up connection" + e.getMessage();
            System.err.println(error);
        }
    }

    public void startServer() {
        System.out.println("Server Started");
        createServerSocket();
        acceptConnections();
    }

}

package advanced.net;

public class LottoProtocol {

    public static final int MAX_VALUE = 49;

    public static final int NUM_OF_NUMBERS = 6;

    public static final String SERVER_HOST = "localhost";

    public static final int SERVER_PORT = 5123;

    public static final String TICKET_REQUEST_COMMAND = "GetTicket";
}
```

I've written println statements to check crucial points in the code. I believe it is where I am telling the thread to start after a client has connected but I cannot follow where the null pointer is from.

Comment: What is the stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: What type of Exception?

Comment: `I cannot follow where the null pointer is from` May you [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37952889/edit) your question to include the stack trace of that `NullPointerException`?

Comment: Pardon my ignorance... how do I use stacktrace/export it so I can attach?

Comment: Answering my stupidity: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors

Comment: Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at advanced.net.LottoServer$ClientRequestHandler.handleClientRequests(LottoServer.java:85)
 at advanced.net.LottoServer$ClientRequestHandler.run(LottoServer.java:112)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you attached the stacktrace of the exception you've mentioned. But leaving that aside, your problem lies (probably - again, no stack trace) in the `handleClientRequests()` method of the `ClientRequestHandler` class, specifically in the following line:

```
request = reader.readLine(); // read client request
```

From `BufferedReader` JavaDocs, `readline()` returns:

> A String containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination characters, or null if the end of the stream has been reached.

So, if your server receives an empty message, the first invocation to `readline()` will return null, and in the next line:

```
if (request.equalsIgnoreCase(LottoProtocol.TICKET_REQUEST_COMMAND)) {
```

you're going to get a `NullPointerException`. As an easy fix, you can reverse this equality check and use:

```
if (LottoProtocol.TICKET_REQUEST_COMMAND.equalsIgnoreCase(request)) {
```

Comment: That solved the issue with the exception but I am not intending that the first call should have a NULL pointer. Once I made the change based on your recommendations I get no exceptions but I am also not getting numbers returned.

Comment: Problem Solved! Had one line of misplaced code. Thank-you so much!